# Failed to Serialization Json to Object which has List object inside (DART)

Tags: android, flutter, serialization, dart

I got an error when serialization. Console log said:

```
> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'forEach'.
> Receiver: "no" Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null) dan
> 0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
> 1      new Article.fromJson (package:tribun_travel/model/article.dart:84:19)
> 2      new ResponseRead.fromJson (package:tribun_travel/model/response_read.dart:16:39)
> 3      BlogRepository.readNewsById (package:tribun_travel/repositories/blog_repository.dart:21:25)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> 4      BlogBloc.mapEventToState (package:tribun_travel/bloc/blog_bloc.dart:28:61) <asynchronous
> suspension>
```

what I did is, I want to make serialization from `json` to Object in Dart. In my class has list object inside. The snippet code wrote like below:

```
class ResponseRead {
  String status;
  String message;
  String source;
  Article data;

  ResponseRead({this.status, this.message, this.source, this.data});

  ResponseRead.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    source = json['source'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Article.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    data['source'] = this.source;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Article{

  String id;
  String fulltexts;
  List<Tag> tag;
  List<Related> related;

  Article(
      {this.id,
        this.fulltexts,
        this.tag,
        this.related
      });

  Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    fulltexts = json['fulltexts'];
    if (json['tag'] != null) {

      tag = new List<Tag>();
      json['tag'].forEach((v) {
        tag.add(new Tag.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['related'] != null) {

      related = new List<Related>();
      json['related'].forEach((v) {
        related.add(new Related.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['fulltexts'] = this.fulltexts;
    if (this.tag != null) {
      data['tag'] = this.tag.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.related != null) {
      data['related'] = this.related.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Article{id: $id, title: $title, photo: $photo}';
  }
}
```

I think there is no problem in my service coz its return what I wanted.
But, why I still has an error when serialization?

**UPDATE**
this is my sample Json file

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Found",
    "source": "memcached",
    "article": {
        "title": "Ini Alasan Pramugari Jarang Sakit Meski Terbang Berjam-jam",
        "fulltexts": "<p><</p>",
        "tag": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "a",
                "alias": "a"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "b",
                "alias": "b"
            }
        ],
        "related": [
            {
                "id": "79224",
            },
            {
                "id": "79219",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: post your input JSON

Comment: i have update the question

Comment: hmmm, looks ok, after `if (json['tag'] != null) {` add `print(json['tag'])` do the same inside `if (json['related'] != null) {`

Comment: i have put `print('apa itu TAG ${json['tag']}');` and it printed `flutter: apa itu TAG no`

Comment: so it is not your JSON - add `print(json)` in `Article.fromJson` ctor

Comment: most likely you need `data = json['article']` not `data = json['data']`

Comment: ops, sorry it's actually `article` = `data`. I just simplified the question by renaming `data` to be `article`

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, did you `print(json)`? if so, what you see? just add that print in `Article.fromJson`

Comment: it printed `flutter: no`. what i mean is, in my true code variable `article` named by `data` just the name

Comment: ok do the same in `ResponseRead.fromJson`: add `print('my json is: $json');`

Comment: i found the problem... yah, its the response `tag` is string `no`. Th It sould be List. thanks man

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be you are expecting the `json['related']` or `json['tag']` in JSON to be a list, but it's actually a string. Check the actual JSON text and you will probably find `"related": "some string"`, not `"related": []`

Please post the actual JSON so that we can find.

Thanks

Comment: Please update the received Json.. It may have the problem. either in "related" or "tag".